# How can a new metric applied for humans causing danger on railtracks?

Tags: computer-vision, human-computer-interaction

I am writing myself and was thinking about, what kind of metric can be applied to measure the "dangerousness" of a human being on a railtrack? For example detecting if a human is running on the rails?

Maybe predicting the human movement towards rails, the distance to the vehicle (ego perspective) or something else?